# Qt - Unable to move scrollbars in QScrollArea

Tags: c++, qt

I have an application that includes a vertical layout of push buttons, which is inside a container widget, which is inside a scroll area, which is part of another layout, which is applied to the main window.  The setup is currently in a working state, and I'm able to scroll using the vertical scrollbar on the right side of the window.

The problem is that this application is meant for a touchscreen, and the default scrollbar is too small for fingers.  I've been able to resize it using `setFixedWidth()` and/or stylesheets; however, the left edge of the scrollbar remains in the same position.  The result is that the scrollbar only expands to the right, putting it off-screen.

I've tried figuring out how to move the scrollbar back to the left so that the entirety of it can be seen on-screen, but I've not been able to find out how to do this yet, as I'm still fairly new to Qt.  I've tried using `setGeometry()`, but it seems to have no effect whatsoever.  I even tried creating a separate `QScrollBar` and adding it manually, but I get the same off-screen result.

Is there something in the layout settings that could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use stylesheets to resize scrollbars:

```
ui->scrollArea->setStyleSheet(QString("\
  QScrollBar:horizontal { height: 30px; } \
  QScrollBar:vertical { width: 30px; }"));
```

Comment: I'm able to change the width; however, even doing so with stylesheets results in the scrollbar expanding off-screen.  Is there a way to use stylesheets to change the scrollbar's x location?  Using scrollArea->verticalScrollBar()->setGeometry(x,y,w,h) doesn't seem to do anything.